# How to display edit/delete button first on Nova laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm new to Nova Laravel. How can I add an action button before id? Action button like edit, delete and view. In some cases,  I have a lot of data in index and difficult to manage action button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if the question is how to move the default action buttons (view, edit, delete) to the left or how to add a button to invoke a custom action.

**In both cases you will need two external packages.**

---

In case you want to **move the standard buttons to the left**:

[Install the package NovaActionsLeft](https://github.com/Flagstudio/nova-actions-left)

OR

In case you want to **add a link to a custom action**:

[Install the package NovaActionButton](https://github.com/pdmfc/nova-action-button)